# How do I replace the harddrive in a Toshiba NB200?

Tags: netbook, computer-building, laptop-repair

I just bought a Toshiba NB200 netbook and I also ordered some SSD drives from Crucial, one of which is going to go into that new device. I expected there to be an easily accessible hdd bay, but there seems to be only one for the RAM.

Before I take my screwdriver and investigate, I'd like to find a tutorial by someone who already did it. I found a YouTube video about it, but it appears to be blocked for copyright reasons, I'm not exactly sure what that's supposed to mean in this context.

I couldn't find anything else helpful. Does someone have a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this link that shows the drive revealed  Looks like it may assist

[NB200 Disassembly](http://www.jayson.in/diy/removing-bios-password-in-toshiba-netbook-nb200.html)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the Satellite and the NB are different models. . .

Comment: Well, there's no battery compartment on my one, the battery is just slid in from the back, so the instructions don't apply.

Comment: Sorry Thought i was Satellite 200.  Is the Netebook NB200

Comment: Hey, we found the same article. Yeah, it does look promising.

Comment: Thanks for the additional research and for going back to the post and updating it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [Service Manual for NB100](http://netbookitalia.it/toshiba-nb100-guida-al-disassemblaggio.html), compare it perhaps? I don't see any for the NB200.

Comment: It seems the harddrive on the nb200 is accessed from below, not from the top as in the nb100.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I found [this article about resetting the BIOS password](http://www.jayson.in/diy/removing-bios-password-in-toshiba-netbook-nb200.html) on the machine and it includes instructions for disassembly with photographs that look promising. The machine seems to be exactly the same I have.

Somewhat hard to find (loads of spammy garbage sites kept littering my search results) and not yet verified, but looking good. A non-standard screwdriver (Torx they are called in Germany) is required.

Comment: Sweet, hope it works out!

Comment: Looks like DaveM had already edited in the same link in his answer (http://superuser.com/questions/80072/how-do-i-replace-the-harddrive-in-a-toshiba-nb200/80075#80075) when I posted this.